# Is it possible to find out current PHP extension API from command line?

Tags: php, version, php-extension

I would like to ask if it is possible to output the currently PHP extension API version from the command line, i.e.:

For example I use PHP 5.6.2 (API 20131226) and I also have PHP 5.5.18 (API 20121212) installed, I can switch between the two versions using the proper **php** command, is there a way to see which API I am using for the currently executed php version of PHP from the terminal??

Checked the `man php` but didn't find anything related this need. 
Also `php -v` or `php --version` didn't show me the API version:

```
$ php -v # or php --version
PHP 5.6.2 (cli) (built: Oct 20 2014 16:21:27) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans
```

The same goes for the 5.5.18 php CLI command.

So, actually, is there a way to accomplish that?

EDIT: found the answer, check the posts below, or the comment of @RichardBernards to this post.

Comment: I think the shell-script of phpize could help you further. Read up on the following answer for an explanation: http://serverfault.com/a/44696

Comment: Yeah, you post the comment while I was posting, the post, I didn't realise I can do it with `phpize`, anyway, thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 7):

Take a closer look to the output of `php -i`. After the list of the loaded configuration files, it shows this info:

```
PHP API => 20121113
PHP Extension => 20121212
Zend Extension => 220121212
Zend Extension Build => API220121212,NTS
PHP Extension Build => API20121212,NTS
```

You can extract what you need like this:

```
php -i | grep 'PHP API'
```

will produce:

```
PHP API => 20121113
```

If you need to extract only the number (to compare it with another number or use it in a script, etc) you can pipe the result further to `cut` or to `sed` to remove the extra characters:

```
php -i | grep 'PHP API' | cut -f2 -d'>'
```

or, better

```
php -i | grep 'PHP API' | sed -e 's/PHP API => //'
```

The one with `cut` will produce the number with a space character in front, the one with `sed` will produce only the number, no padding.

Answer (score 1):

This provides extension dir which last part is API version:

`php-config --extension-dir`

It is also posible select data for specific version of PHP, e.g. 7.2:

`php-config7.2 --extension-dir`

Extract just API version by passing it to basename:

`basename $(php-config7.2 --extension-dir)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help ?

```
php -i | grep version
```

Comment: `phpize -v | grep Zend\ M | grep -oE '([0-9]+)'` for only the API number, so you can store it in a variable!